# Is there any way to fix USRP that doesn't connect?

Tags: gnuradio, usrp

I am new to SDR. But I have an USRP X310. Installed UHD and GNU Radio from source on Ubuntu 20.04. Connected to the USRP with SFP+ through the port 1 and powered the USRP. But the LED of the ethernet port doesn’t light up at all. And it seems like the computer also doesn’t see the device.

Checked with other cables and with the port 0, but it is still the case. Does that mean USRP is broken?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a signal processing question.

Comment: Please don't post the same question to three sites ([1](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/87360), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75927570/is-there-any-way-to-fix-usrp-that-doesnt-connect), [3](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/21807/is-there-any-way-to-fix-usrp-that-doesnt-connect)) in verbatim copy within 45 minutes without as much as mentioning it. Duplicating community effort is understandably generally frowned upon!

Comment: My suggestion is to contact Ettus for support.